# I can't execute functions because of another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to change photos in a modal window by swiping my finger in two directions, and this piece of code from the Internet helped:

```or-tag-here
function swipedetect(el, callback) {

    var touchsurface = el,
        swipedir,
        startX,
        startY,
        distX,
        distY,
        threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
        restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
        allowedTime = 300, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
        elapsedTime,
        startTime,
        handleswipe = callback || function (swipedir) {}

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        swipedir = 'none'
        dist = 0
        startX = touchobj.pageX
        startY = touchobj.pageY
        startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime) { // first condition for swipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint) { // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipedir = (distX < 0) ? 'left' : 'right' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
            } else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint) { // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipedir = (distY < 0) ? 'up' : 'down' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
            }
        }
        handleswipe(swipedir)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
};
```

But when I wanted to use it this way:

```or-tag-here
    let modall = document.getElementById('modall');
    swipedetect(modall, function(swipedir) {
        if (swipedir == 'right') plusSlides(-1);

        if (swipedir == 'left') plusSlides(1);
    });
```

`closeModal()` function and others in this modal stopped working. Could somebody say why?

P.S `closeModal()` and other  functions are executed only when I click on some element. Everything was working before I pasted swiping code. **Swiping code only works on touch screens, but it doesn't work on a computer, so **`closeModal()`** works without problems on a PC.**

Comment: Where is `closeModal` defined? Where is the modal defined? Where are the events hooked up to the elements?

Comment: Each function is defined in a single file, and `closeModal()` only assigns `display:none` to block when I click the cancel button. Only the last section of the code is written in the HTML file.

Comment: I should have been more specific. Please include all relevant code in the question, as a [mre]. There's no way for use to reproduce the problem from the code given.